# latex2latex without \ref

Tags: hyperref, latex2rtf

I want to submit a manuscript to an academic journal (my first article). Obviously, I created a beautiful pdf using latex with figures, equations, an appendices and cross-references (package: *hyperref*).

Unfortunately, the journal only accepts .tex files with certain constraints. For example, the main document needs to be a separate file from the appendix. The journal will do the final compiling.

The main issue is that I have many cross-references going back-and-forth between the main body and the appendix. Can I convert my *latex2latex* such that all `Equation~\ref{LabelToEquation3.2}` are converted to the text `Equation~3.2` etc.?

Comment: If all they need is a separate PDF, one would simply copy and paste the pages into two files.  If all they need is a separate .tex file, use \include or \includeonly.

Comment: They need a tex for the main body (or, at least, an editable document). Could you elaborate on the last part of your comment?

Comment: One can split your source into 2 or more files and join them together using \input or \include (\include forces a page break before and after).  \includeonly can be used to not print all the files but still include references (aux files).

Comment: Wouldn't I then still have a main-body-tex file with \ref{AppendixLabel} commands? If I send this tex file to the journal, without the appendix, it wouldn't make sense.

Comment: If you use the `xr`  package you should be able  to make \label/\ref work across the documents

Comment: I am not sure what xr does, but I don't want these labels to work. I want them gone. I want pure strings.

Comment: The same applies to \cite{}. This should become "[4]", for example.

Comment: I think you are creating a lot more work than is needed.  If the journal routinely uses LaTeX source, then they be used to aux file references.

Comment: why do you want them gone? that is not implied by the constraints that you specified, but if so just your editor to replace each \ref by the relevant number (just go through the list in the aux file)

Comment: @John Kormylo I am not sure if this journal routinely uses latex. I have no way of testing the final layout of my publication until, well, publication...

Comment: @David Carlisle Indeed possible, but tedious. Also, I'd rather learn a quick method now and save myself time with future publications too.

Comment: well use xr then:-)